# showing ($\psi - \text{ id}_V)(W) = W$ iff $U \cap W = \{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite $K$-vector space of dimension $n$. let $\phi$ and $\psi$ be linear transformations from $V \longrightarrow V$ such that $\psi \circ \phi = \phi \circ \psi$. Let
$$ W := \{v \in V | \phi(v)=v \} \text{ and } U := \{v \in V | \psi(v)=v \}.$$

How do I show:  $$(\psi - \text{ id}_V)(W) = W \text{ iff } U \cap W = \{0\}?$$

I've already shown the following from the previous part of the question:

1. ($\psi - \text{ id}_V)(W) \subseteq W$,
2. $W \neq \lbrace 0 \rbrace  \text{ iff } \det(\text{Id}_n -A)=0$,

where $A :=$ the matrix of $\phi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From basic linear algebra, we know that $W$ is an invariant subspace of $\psi$ (hence an invariant subspace of $\psi-id$).

$(\psi -id)(W)=W$

iff $\psi -id$ is invertible on $W$

iff for any $0\neq w\in W$, $(\psi -id)(w)\neq 0$

iff $U\cap W=0$

We are done.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain a little more how the before last statement implies the last one. Also if I understood correctly, for $w \neq 0$,  $(\psi - id)(w) \neq 0$ because if it was zero then we would have $dim(W) > dim((\psi -id)(W))$  which contradicts that $W = (\psi -id)(W)$ ?

Comment: never mind I think I got it. it's because $U = ker(\psi -id)$ right?

Comment: @yasrey1710 That's right, $U$ is the kernel of $\psi - id$